# RepeatButton for Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, repeatbutton

Is there anything like RepeatButton in Windows Forms? 
How can I implement same behavior using an ordinary button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not out of the box, but you can build your own.  Here's an example: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/RepeatButton.aspx