# Increasing an integer value while keeping button pressed and stoping when released, in windows form

Tags: winforms, visual-c++

I have a code like this in windows form , c++

```
private: System::Void button3_MouseUp(Object^  sender, MouseEventArgs^  e) {
         _run=false;
         }
private: System::Void button3_MouseDown(Object^  sender, MouseEventArgs^  e) {
         _run = true;
         MyAction();
         }

private: System::Void MyAction()
         {
           while(_run)
           {
               i=i+1;
            System::Console::WriteLine( i );
           }
         }
```

The motivation was to keep the value of "i" (i is an integer ) going up till the time I press the the button and stoping when I release the button . But one i press the button , value of i increses and the UI hangs and never stops ,
Any one have any suggession to solve this issue

Comment: possible duplicate of [RepeatButton for Winforms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3727715/repeatbutton-for-winforms)

Answer (score 0):

You need to pump the message loop in your `MyAction` method.  In C# and VB it would be something like `Application.DoEvents()`

Since this all runs on the UI thread, your loop blocks execution of anything else on the UI thread, including the message pump.  By calling `Application.DoEvents` (or the C++ equivalent) you let the window message pump (wndproc) run, which processes window messages and dispatches events (calls button3_MouseUp() when appropriate).

Comment: I managed to use a timer in the windows form , and set it to work on MouseDown event and stopped it on MouseUp event